# How can i get cookie in react?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, next.js

I can't get my cookie

I use react-cookie, react-cookies and document.cookie 
but nothing working

this is cookie sended from server(by passport)

```
name: mbsb
value: ...
Domain: localhost
Path: /
Expires: Session
Size: 86
HttpOnly: true
Priority: Midium
```

how can I get this cookie in react ???

Comment: What's the reason for having the cookie in JS?

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie is `HttpOnly` cookie and cannot be accessed on the client side. Instead you should use the middleware on the server ( like express ) and parse the cookie value and then return it to the client.

If this is the case, follow these steps to get to your solve.

1. Setup an API Route if using NextJS
2. The API route uses passport, accesses the return value and then returns the final cookie values or decision to the client.
3. The client can then use these values to further take action.

See these references for Server side controller code:

- https://auth0.com/blog/next-js-authentication-tutorial/ - Relevant if using NextJS
- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-remember-me